Code for PL/SQL Pascal Triangle and pyramid
I need the PL/SQL code for SQL*Plus.
I get:
1

2 2

3 3 3

4 4 4 4

Output should be:
   1 
 
  2 2
 
 3 3 3
 
4 4 4 4 

Code:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000

DECLARE 
    i NUMBER;
    j NUMBER;
    total_lines  NUMBER := 4;  -- Number of lines for the pyramid
    leading_ spaces NUMBER;
    line_output VARCHAR2(100); -- Variable to hold each line's output
BEGIN
    -- Loop through each line to create the pyramid   
    FOR i IN 1..total_lines LOOP
        -- Calculate leading spaces for centering the line
        leading_spaces := total_lines - i;

        -- Initialize the line output with leading spaces
        line_output := LPAD(' ', leading_spaces);

        -- Append numbers to the line output
        FOR j IN 1..i LOOP
            line_output := line_output || i || ' ';
        END LOOP;

        -- Print the line output
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(line_output);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

The code does not give the correct output, but:
1

2 2

3 3 3

4 4 4 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 

It should be:
   1 

  2 2

 3 3 3

4 4 4 4 

but with no space between.

You are doing:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000

You need to do:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000 FORMAT WRAPPED

Without format wrapped, the leading spaces you're generating are discarded.
The documentation isn't very clear on this, but it does say for word_wrapped that:

When WORD_WRAPPED is enabled, each line of server output is wrapped within the line size specified by SET LINESIZE. Lines are broken on word boundaries. SQL*Plus left justifies each line, skipping all leading whitespace.

The "skipping all leading whitespace" only applies to word_wrapped, not wrapped.
It doesn't seem to say that word_wrapped is the default, but if you start a new session and do show serveroutput you can see that it is.

It has something to do with tool being unable to properly display what you wanted.
This is SQL*Plus; instead of an ordinary space character, I'm using a non-breakable space (chr(160)) and the result is
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SQL> DECLARE
  2     i               NUMBER;
  3     j               NUMBER;
  4     total_lines     NUMBER := 4;                         -- Number of lines for the pyramid
  5     leading_spaces  NUMBER;
  6     line_output     VARCHAR2 (100);                  -- Variable to hold each line's output
  7  BEGIN
  8     -- Loop through each line to create the pyramid
  9     FOR i IN 1 .. total_lines
 10     LOOP
 11        -- Calculate leading spaces for centering the line
 12        leading_spaces := total_lines - i;
 13
 14        -- Initialize the line output with leading spaces
 15        line_output := LPAD (chr(160), leading_spaces, chr(160));
 16
 17        -- Append numbers to the line output
 18        FOR j IN 1 .. i
 19        LOOP
 20           line_output := line_output || i || chr(160);
 21        END LOOP;
 22
 23        -- Print the line output
 24        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (line_output);
 25     END LOOP;
 26  END;
 27  /
   1 
  2 2 
 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>


The same code results in this in TOAD and SQL Developer:


You can use:
DECLARE 
  total_lines CONSTANT NUMBER := 4;  -- Number of lines for the pyramid
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..total_lines LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      LPAD(' ', total_lines - i, ' ')
      || RPAD(i, 2*i - 1, ' ' || i)
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
   1
  2 2
 3 3 3
4 4 4 4

And if you want to format it neatly for more than 9 rows:
DECLARE 
  total_lines  CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 10;  -- Number of lines for the pyramid
  term_width   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH(total_lines);
  padding_char CONSTANT CHAR(1) := ' ';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..total_lines LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      LPAD(padding_char, term_width * (total_lines - i), padding_char)
      || RPAD(
           LPAD(i, term_width, padding_char),
           (2 * i - 1)*term_width,
           LPAD(i, 2 * term_width, padding_char)
        )
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
                   1
                 2   2
               3   3   3
             4   4   4   4
           5   5   5   5   5
         6   6   6   6   6   6
       7   7   7   7   7   7   7
     8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10

fiddle
